# jasper reports file not found exception need help please

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports

hi friends am trying to pass a couple of parameter through hashmap to the jasper report, am getting the file not found exception but my file is placed under netbeans project folder,the below is my java code

```
   try{ HashMap hmp = new HashMap();
        hmp.put("mytin", m_t_n);
         hmp.put("cname", c_n_m);
         hmp.put("invno", c_in);
         hmp.put("ctin", c_t);
         hmp.put("date", c_d);
         hmp.put("time", c_m);
         hmp.put("gtot", gt);
         hmp.put("dis", dcn);
         hmp.put("adj", amtn);
         hmp.put("fin", fn_am);

        JasperReport jrpt = null;
         String srcd="report1.jrxml";
        JasperPrint jp;
        //jrpt = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(getClass().getResource(srcd));
jrpt = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(new File(srcd));
         jp=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jrpt,hmp, DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/billing", "root", ""));
           JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jp,false);
           jv.setFitWidthZoomRatio();
           jv.setVisible(true);
}
catch(Exception er){
}
```

the error i get is

```
run:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: report1.jrxml
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: report1.jrxml
```

kindly help me to resolve this error thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the file stored (in relationship to the source)?  `jrxml` needs to be compiled before it can be filled

Comment: yeas jrxml is stored inside the netbeans project folder

Comment: Where abouts within the project folder?  Within the `src` folder?  In what directory structure?

Comment: inside the src folder ...

Comment: Assuming it's not in the same package as the class that's loading it, you should be able to use something like `getClass().getResource("/path/to/report/report1/jrxml");`

Comment: nope its in the same package only wat to do any help

Comment: jpr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(getClass().getResource("C:\\Users\\Applebj\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication14\\src\\report\\report1.jrxml")); 

this is my file path see it

Comment: hey am getting the error for the above given statements 
no suitable method found for compileReport(URL) method JasperCompileManager.compileReport(String) is not applicable (argument mismatch; URL cannot be converted to String) method JasperCompileManager.compileReport(InputStream) is not applicable (argument mismatch; URL cannot be converted to InputStream) method JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperDesign) is not applicable (argument mismatch; URL cannot be converted to JasperDesign

Comment: You can still use the absolute path, as src been the root, to the resource, as suggested above. The attempt to use the String path has failed because the API doesn't support that form

Comment: hey if i use the above suggested one means am getting the error still plzz help me to resolve it kindly

Comment: GetResource should work. Does the report contain sub reports

Comment: no am creating a single report which consist of 3 tables thats all if i give the get resource means am getting the error as i said

error  -:no suitable method found for compileReport(URL) method JasperCompileManager.compileReport(String) is not applicable (argument mismatch; URL cannot be converted to String) method JasperCompileManager.compileReport(InputStream) is not applicable (argument mismatch; URL cannot be converted to InputStream) method JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperDesign) is not applicable (argument mismatch; URL cannot be converted to JasperDesign

Comment: As I said, there simply is no method that take a String, what more do you want me to say

Comment: then how should i pass my file path don't have any idea can u plzz provide me a code snippet plzz

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that your class file and `report1.jrxml` are stored within the same package within your project...

```
src/some/package/name/Report.java
src/some/package/name/report1.jrxml
```

Then, you should be able to use `getClass().getResource("report1.jrxml")` to obtain a `URL` reference to the resource

If the does work, then you need to try something like `getClass().getResource("/some/package/name/report1.jrxml")`.  If that fails, then there is something wrong with the file.  Either it's not where you think it is or it is corrupted in some way...

A `jrxml` file is just a `XML` file used by JasperReports, it needs to be compiled first before it can be used...

```
try{ 
    HashMap hmp = new HashMap();
    hmp.put("mytin", m_t_n);
    hmp.put("cname", c_n_m);
    hmp.put("invno", c_in);
    hmp.put("ctin", c_t);
    hmp.put("date", c_d);
    hmp.put("time", c_m);
    hmp.put("gtot", gt);
    hmp.put("dis", dcn);
    hmp.put("adj", amtn);
    hmp.put("fin", fn_am);

    JasperReport jrpt = null;
    String srcd="report1.jrxml";
    JasperPrint jp;
    jrpt = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(getClass().getResource(srcd));
    //jrpt = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(new File(srcd));
    jp=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jrpt,hmp, DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/billing", "root", ""));
    JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jp,false);
    jv.setFitWidthZoomRatio();
    jv.setVisible(true);
} catch(Exception er){
    er.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
try {
            String reportSource = "resources/report1.jrxml";
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, new JREmptyDataSource());
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: resources should be my folder name where the jrxmll file is stored am i right

Comment: Yes..in your case it can be just `String reportSource = "report1.jrxml";`

Comment: ok in my case am having the jrxml file in the same folder where my project consist of so i think don't need specify my folder name instead i can simply give the direct file name is it okay

Comment: hey when i click my jbutton the report is not invoked
i get the following exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: report1.jrxml (The system cannot find the file specified)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: report1.jrxml (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Ok.then this may work.can you try this - `JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(getClass().getResource("/report1.jrxml"));`

Comment: hey is it possible to do that b'coz i have tried and got the error as
no suitable method found for compileReport(URL)
    method JasperCompileManager.compileReport(String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URL cannot be converted to String)
    method JasperCompileManager.compileReport(InputStream) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URL cannot be converted to InputStream)
    method JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperDesign) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URL cannot be converted to JasperDesign)
----